# Scheme binary search tree

Tags: scheme, racket

I have already defined helper functions to be:

```
;; returns value of node
(define (value node)
  (if (null? node) '()
      (car node)))

;; returns left subtree of node
(define (left node)
  (if (null? node) '()
      (cadr node)))

;; returns right subtree of node
(define (right node)
  (if (null? node) '()
      (caddr node)))
```

and I am trying to write a function `leaves` that returns a list with the leaves of the tree in order of left to right.

```
(define (leaves tree)
    (if (and (?null (left tree)) (?null (right tree)))
        ???
        (leaves (left tree)) (leaves (right tree))))
```

but that is as far as I can get

ex: (leaves '(1 (2 () ()) (3 () ()))) should evaluate to '(2 3)

Comment: Start by defining what a tree is. Can you write down a data definition for a tree? Otherwise it will be hard for anyone to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what you have so far, the `???` is going to need to evaluate to the value of the leaf, ie. `(value node)` because it is the base case of your iteration.  Also, you're going to need to combine the values you get back from the base case in your iteration case.  `list` is usually a good first candidate to try when you need to combine multiple results `cons` is usually my second try.  Taking those suggestions, your `leaves` function looks like this:

```
(define (leaves tree)
    (if (and (null? (left tree)) (null? (right tree)))
        (value tree)
        (list (leaves (left tree)) (leaves (right tree)))))
```

which, when run on your sample of `(leaves '(1 (2 () ()) (3 () ())))` does indeed evaluate to `(2 3)`.

HOWEVER; YOU'RE NOT DONE!  We're only testing with 1 level of recursion.  What if we make a bigger tree?  Something like: `(leaves '(1 (2 (4 () ()) (5 () ())) (3 (6 () ()) (7 () ()))))`  Running this gives `((4 5) (6 7))`.  Those are the right values in the right order, but we have too much structure in there, too many parenthesis.  This is a typical problem you will encounter throughout your scheme career, so let me explain why it happens, and how you can go about attacking the problem.

If look at the two branches of our `if` form, you'll notice that `(value tree)` returns an atom, or a number in this case.  The else branch takes two of `???` and turns it into a list of `???`.  We're going to be executing the else branch multiple times - any time we're not in the base case.  This means we're going to continue to wrap, and wrap, and wrap into a deeper and deeper list structure.  So here's what we do about it.

Lets return a list in our base case, and keep our list flat in the recursion case.  To return a list in our base case it is as simple as returning `(list (value tree))` instead of just `(value tree)`.  In the recursion case, we need a function that takes 2 lists and combines them without making a deeper list.  Such a function does exist - `append`.  So let's look at what our `leaves` function looks like now:

```
(define (leaves tree)
        (if (and (null? (left tree)) (null? (right tree)))
            (list (value tree))
            (append (leaves (left tree)) (leaves (right tree)))))
```

**Intermezzo - Test cases**

Racket has test suite library that has a very low barrier to entry called [rackunit](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/quick-start.html).  Let's throw together a few quick test cases at the bottom of the file.

```
(require rackunit)
;;empty tree
(check-equal? (leaves '()) '())

;;simple balanced tree
(check-equal?
 (leaves '(1 (2 () ()) (3 () ())))
 '(2 3))

;;larger balanced tree
(check-equal?
 (leaves '(1 (2 (4 () ()) (5 () ())) (3 (6 () ()) (7 () ()))))
 '(4 5 6 7))

;;unbalanced tree
(check-equal?
 (leaves '(1 (2 (4 () ()) ()) (3 () ())))
 '(4 3))
```

Recently, racket has added support for [submodules](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2012/06/submodules.html) and specific support for test submodules if you are curious and want to look into them.

---

Back to our leaves problem.  Running our tests, we notice our function doesn't behave well on unbalanced trees.  We get extra `()`s when we have a node that only has 1 leaf.  That is because we are traversing both the left and the right subtrees whenever we're at a node that isn't a leaf.  What we really need are two more cases in our `if`.  We could nest the `if`s, but scheme's `cond` form makes better sense.

Now, the template we're aiming to fill out is:

```
(define (leaves tree)
  (cond [(leaf? tree) (...)]
    [(and (has-left? tree) (has-right? tree)) 
     (...)]
    [(has-left? tree) (...)]
    [(has-right? tree) (...)]
    [else (error "should never get here")]))
```

I'll stop there in-case this is homework, and to give you the satisfaction of understanding and solving this the rest of the way.  I hope my explanations have given you more direction that just "here's the code" answers.

Answer (score 1):

Well this seems like you're doing [Breadth First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) but with the alteration that you don't print yourself if you have two children (or just one, if you don't want to print nodes that only have one child).

I would aim for solving that first, and then changing your solution to that to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (list-of-leaves tree)
  (if(leaf? tree)
     (list (node tree))
     (cond((right-branch-only? tree)(list-of-leaves (right-branch tree)))
          ((left-branch-only? tree)(list-of-leaves (left-branch tree)))
          (else(append (list-of-leaves (left-branch tree))
                       (list-of-leaves (right-branch tree)))))))
```